# MySQL select equals condition work as like condition

Tags: mysql

I got today strange results, when I use query

```
 SELECT id, zip FROM `Locations` WHERE zip = '4000XXXXX'
```

Which simply fetchs id and zip code where zip code should be equals to condition. 
Schema:

```
zip int(11)
```

I have in table rows with zip values `4000` and expected result of this query is no result.

Simply - equals condition works as like condition where there is string and type of column is int. Whats going on ?

[image: Picture]

Comment: Note that `INT` is not an appropriate data type for a U.S. postal code, which is not actually a numeric value *per se*, but rather a 5, 9, or 10 character string value with valid character values [0-9] (and also `-` at position 6 if 10 characters).  A more appropriate data type is `CHAR(9) COLLATE ascii_bin` (or 5 or 10). (ASCII collation is far more efficient, because it is never going to be multibyte). You simply won't get consistently sane behavior by treating a string of digits  as a number, because it is in fact not a number -- it only looks like one.

Comment: Yes, you're totally right, thanks. Int type was there by mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do *you* expect would be the result of a string and an int?

In order to make a sensable comparison, MySql tries to cast the `string` to an `int` by taking the left most digits.
In this case the casting gives `4000`, hence you'll get all the rows with `zip=4000`

Comment: From one point it makes sense, from the other it doesn't have any as equals should be equals.

Comment: @kxyz, after the string is implicitly cast to a number, it is exactly equal.  See also [Can I configure MySQL's typecasting to consider 0 != 'foo'?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36100/11651).